# Waiting for external launched process product finish to continue

Tags: python, subprocess, system-calls, wait

I have a Python code in which some functions that call to external processes are defined. Each process launched by each function generate a final product that is needed to run the next function. The problem is that the script is not waiting the external background process to finish (I am processing some heavy images so the process takes a while).

I've tried launching the external process with `os.system()`, `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.run()` but none of them worked. I've also attempted with `time.sleep()` and `Event().wait()`, but they don't work either as they stop the external background process too.

Part of the code: when the `cmd` string is called, an external process is launched to a image processing program.
The error is obtained when `function` is called for the second time even if the product of the first call is not finished.

Maybe the problem could be that there is not a specific product in return in the functions, so Python does not recognize when the product is finished.

```
import subprocess 


def function(directory, exe, a, b):    
    cmd = directory + exe + a + b
    subprocess.run(cmd)
 

function(directory1, exe1, a1, b1)
function(directory2, exe2, a2, b2) #directory2 is where the product obtained from function1 is saved. 
function(directory3, exe3, a3, b3) #directory3 is where the product obtained from funciton2 is saved.
```

Is there any way to stop executing following comands until a product is obtained, not stopping background processes?

Any help? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Seems that your process is immediately going to background. May you send to it some argument to prevent this? `subprocess.run` really should block until the process finish so it is something fishy here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run
What is the executable argument? Does it even run at all? May you test it with `print(subprocess.run(cmd))`?

Comment: Also may you put `print(cmd)` before the `subprocess.run` call?

Comment: The executable argument seems something like this: 'C:\\LAStools\\bin\\las2las -i C:\\directory\\*.laz -drop_intensity_below 1000 -keep_class 2 3 4 5 -odir C:\\directory\\ -olaz'. It calls to the LAStools software and execute the arguments. I test if it is running (print(subprocess.run(cmd)). In fact, the process starts running but stops when the error from function2 appears.

Comment: What exactly does `print(subprocess.run(cmd)` return?

Comment: CompletedProcess(args='...', returncode=0). I can't put all the args as it's too long for the characters allowed in the comments, but it coincides with the cmd introduced.

Comment: Hmm, `returncode=0` does mean that it terminated correctly. All right, let me provide some answer.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, try add a bit more of debug output:

```py
import subprocess 
from subprocess import PIPE


def function(directory, exe, a, b):    
    cmd = directory + exe + a + b
    print("Running", cmd)

    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    print("Return code:", result.returncode)
    print("STDOUT:", result.stdout)
    print("STDERR:", result.stderr)
 

function(directory1, exe1, a1, b1)
function(directory2, exe2, a2, b2) #directory2 is where the product obtained from function1 is saved. 
function(directory3, exe3, a3, b3)
```